# Webmin: New Virtualhost Apache configuration is incorrect, how to fix?

Tags: apache-http-server, webmin

Whenever I create a new site on one one of my servers which runs Apache 2.4, after visiting the URL, I'm being redirected ot the default website on that server.

When I look in the config file, I see the following in the header: `<VirtualHost *:80>`

As soon as I change the * to the external IP of the server and restart apache2, it works!

This question remains: How can I fix this permanently? I already changed my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default config file to have the external IP of this machine instead of *:80 in the VirtualHost header.

Also, here's an image of the Apache configuration in Webmin where you can clearly see that it figured that the test domain 'test.nl' would listen to *:80 instead of the common IP of that server: [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7205355/virtualmin.png]